# set value toFixed on blur

Tags: jquery

I have an input field that is used to insert a dollar amount.  If the user types in "100" or "100." I want to add two decimal places to the value using the toFixed(2) method.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8d4Px/)

This is what I have tried:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('#ccAmt').blur(function() {
        j$(this).val(j$(this).val().toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

I found several examples on the forum, but everything I tried didn't work.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `.val()` returning a Number?  Try:

```
j$(this).val(parseFloat(j$(this).val()).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Thank you! It was returning a string. parseFloat fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/evanax/4/edit)***

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();


j$(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#ccAmt').blur(function() {
        var val = parseFloat( this.value ).toFixed(2);
        $(this).val( val );
    });

})(jQuery);
```